# UICollectionViewFlowLayout with different cell sizes unintentionally aligns cells from center

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, flowlayout

I'm working on an IOS app which requires UICollectionView with different cells with different cell sizes.
I sucsessfully implemented the UICollectionView based on those requirements, but for some reason, **it made the smaller cells align from center**:

[image]

All the code is implemented in a single viewController, [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/PyZ6wAVY)

Can someone help me figure out **how to align the cell from the left**, like it does in the most basic implementation (unified size for all cells).

It seems that the size differences messes with the collection layout..

Any help will be much appreciated!